# Repeating replacement pattern number of times in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to do the following in vim.

- Replace `a,2` with `a@,a@`
- Replace `b,3` with `b@,b@,b@`
- Replace `c,6` with `c@,c@,c@,c@,c@,c@`
  and so on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's another case for the powerful `:help sub-replace-expression`:

```
:%s/\(\w\),\(\d\+\)/\=join(repeat([submatch(1) . '@'], submatch(2)), ',')/g
```

This matches a *word* character (`\w`) followed by `,` and a number, appends `@` to each matched word character (`submatch(1) . '@`), turns that into a *List* (`[...]`), multiplies the List element according to the matched number (`repeat()`), then `join()`s that back into a `,`-separated string, which is used as the replacement.

This is based on your example; you need to tweak the pattern according to your particular needs.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Did a Google search on this. Didn't get the answer at all. The repeat function was what I was looking for.

Comment: Try Vim's `:help` next time.

Answer (score 2):

vim has `repeat()` function. This command should do what you want:

```
%s/\v([a-z]),(\d+)/\=substitute(repeat(submatch(1).'@,',submatch(2)),',$','','g')/g
```

Note that this line will change `foo,3abc` into `foo@,o@,o@abc`. The result might be not exactly what you are looking for, but by reading the command, you should know the idea, you can change it to make it fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim
Snippet like SublimeText Editor

Example

```
snippet doctype XHTML 1.0 Transitional
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

if you type

```
doctype XHTML 1.0 Transitional
```

and press [TAB] - u take autocompleted text

u can use parameters like

```
snippet proto
${1:class_name}.prototype.${2:method_name} =
function(${3:first_argument}) {
    ${4:// body...}
};
```

:-)